# SUM depending on column value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, spreadsheet

I have a table that looks like this:

[image]

In cell F2 I would like to have the sum of all values in column B where the value in the cell next to it (C column) is equal to "Niels".

How could I do this? (I'm a beginner with Excel)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with SUMIF():

```
=SUMIF(C:C,"Niels",B:B)
```

You can also use the data in E directly in the formula so you do not need to retype the formula for each, in E2 put just `Niels`

```
=SUMIF(C:C,E2,B:B)
```

Then you can copy down.

Comment: They would have to edit the E column to exactly match their lookup string.

Comment: @HackSlash Hence the `in E2 put just Niels`.